# .map-style querying using .where in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Take this scenario:

To view the company counts of all items, I can write:

```
@counts = Item.all.collect{|i| i.companies.count}
```

Is it possible to do a similar thing with `.where` to return ONLY those items which have `count > 0`?

```
@items_with_companies = Item.where{|i| i.companies.count > 0}
```

For clarity **I don't need a specific answer to the above case** - I'm looking for a general solution that would allow far more flexibility in my querying than I currently use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective way to do it is to add a counter cache column to Item

```
class Item
  # items must have a column named companies_count
  has_many :companies, :counter_cache => true
  scope :with_companies, where('companies_count>0')
end
```

There are other ways, doing subqueries or join & group & count, for instance.

The important thing is, everything you write in `where` will run in the database, so it's limited to what SQL can do.